# How can plot with using the outputs of optimization problem?

Tags: python, optimization, plot

I want to plot S,I,H,L in the following  python code. for this purpose I need to use optimized outputs. for example for plotting `S`, I need `x[0],x[1]` and `x[8]` from outputs. for `I`, need `x[2],x[3]` and `x[9]`. for `H` , need `x[4],x[5]` and `x[10]`. for `L`, need `x[6],x[7]`and `x[11]`. all of these function defined in terms of x elements before.  How can I do this?

```
 import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from scipy.special import roots_legendre, eval_legendre

from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint
# create variables
n=2;z=1;m=2;a=0;b=1
x = [sp.symbols('x%d' % i) for i in range(8*n-4)]
#x=sp.symbols('x:20')
#t=sp.symbols('t ')
from sympy.abc import t
B=zeros(n,n)
number = range(n)
for i in number:
   for j in number:
       if i<j :
           B[i,j]=0
       else :
           B[i,j]=sp.factorial(i+j)/(2**j*sp.factorial(j)*sp.factorial(i-j))
PS=Matrix(1,n,x[0:n]);PI=Matrix(1,n,x[n:2*n]);PH=Matrix(1,n,x[2*n:3*n]);PL=Matrix(1,n,x[3*n:4*n])
TS=[[1]];TI=[[1]];TH=[[1]];TL=[[1]]
for i in range(n-1):
    TS.append([t**(x[4*n+i]+i+1)])
    TI.append([t**(x[5*n+i-1]+i+1)])
    TH.append([t**(x[6*n+i-2]+i+1)])
    TL.append([t**(x[7*n+i-3]+i+1)])
MTS=Matrix(TS);MTI=Matrix(TI);MTH=Matrix(TH);MTL=Matrix(TL)
S=PS*B*MTS;I=PI*B*MTI;H=PH*B*MTH;L=PL*B*MTL
#CONVERT SYMPY MATRICES TO NUMPY ONE
S0=np.array(S);I0=np.array(I);H0=np.array(H);L0=np.array(L)
GS=zeros(n,n);GI=zeros(n,n);GH=zeros(n,n);GL=zeros(n,n)
for i in range(n):
   if i==0:
      GS[i,i]=0
      GI[i,i]=0
      GH[i,i]=0
      GL[i,i]=0
   else:
      GS[i,i]=simplify(gamma(x[4*n+i-1]+i+1)/gamma(x[4*n+i-1]+i+1-z))
      GI[i,i]=simplify(gamma(x[5*n+i-2]+i+1)/gamma(x[5*n+i-2]+i+1-z))
      GH[i,i]=simplify(gamma(x[6*n+i-3]+i+1)/gamma(x[6*n+i-3]+i+1-z))
      GL[i,i]=simplify(gamma(x[7*n+i-4]+i+1)/gamma(x[7*n+i-4]+i+1-z))
DS=simplify(t**(-z)*PS*B*GS*MTS)
DI=simplify(t**(-z)*PI*B*GI*MTI)
DH=simplify(t**(-z)*PH*B*GH*MTH)
DL=simplify(t**(-z)*PL*B*GL*MTL)
RS=DS[0,0]-(.0043217-.125*S[0,0]*I[0,0]-(.002+.0008)*S[0,0])
RI=DI[0,0]-(.125*S[0,0]*I[0,0]+.0056*H[0,0]*I[0,0]+.029*L[0,0]-(.002+.0008+.025+.35)*I[0,0])
RH=DH[0,0]-(.535-.0056*H[0,0]*I[0,0]+.35*I[0,0]-(.002+.0008)*H[0,0])
RL=DL[0,0]-(.025*I[0,0]-(.002+.0008+.029)*L[0,0])
#f = lambdify(t, R)
def R(s):
   return (RS**2+RI**2+RH**2+RL**2).subs(t,s)
r, w = roots_legendre(m)
w=zeros(1,m)
I1=0
for i in range (m):
   w[i]=R((b-a)/2*r[i]+(b+a)/2)
   I1=I1+w[i]
I2=((b-a)/2)*I1

t = next(s for s in S.free_symbols if s.name == 't')
x = [
    next(s for s in I2.free_symbols if s.name == f'x{i}')
    for i in range(8*n - 4)
]
args = [t, *x]
I2 = sp.lambdify(args, I2)
S = sp.lambdify(args, S.flat()[0])
I = sp.lambdify(args, I.flat()[0])
H = sp.lambdify(args, H.flat()[0])
L = sp.lambdify(args, L.flat()[0])

def objective(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return I2(*params)

def Sc(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return S(*params)
def Ic(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return I(*params)
def Hc(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return H(*params)
def Lc(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return L(*params)

res = minimize(
    fun=objective,
    x0=np.ones(1 + 8*n-4),
    constraints=(
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Sc, lb=.1, ub=.1),
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Ic, lb=.2, ub=.2),
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Hc, lb=.3, ub=.3),
        NonlinearConstraint(fun=Lc, lb=.4, ub=.4),
    ),
)
assert res.success, res.message
```